# Ant Code Review 

Tags: ant

folks!

I have two questions (may be stupid).

Say, there are three code excerpts:

```
(1) <target name="test1" depends="INIT">
(2) <target name="test2" depends="INIT">
(3) <target name="TEST3" depends="INIT, test1, test2">
```

and the TEST3 is a default target of a project.

How many times does INIT executes?

Is it a good idea to extract, for example, macrodefs in a separate file and then include it into the main file (some kind of modules)

Comment: Just put an <echo message="INIT executed" /> in your init-target :-)

Comment: Thank you! Only one time. So that Ant tracks targets. What about the second part? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only once. 
When `test2/TEST3` will execute, it will know that `INIT` has already been executed.

Also, the target **depends** on `INIT`, i.e., for the execution of that target, `INIT` must have been executed already, if not... then **only** execution will go to `INIT`.